# Converting a JSON object with multiple lists as fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using jackson's ObjectMapper to convert JSON files into Java objects.
How do I convert a JSON object that has an array as one of its fields? Example below:

```
{
  "list":[
    {
      "value":"example"
    },
    {
      "value":"example2"
    }
  ]
}
```

`ObjectMapper` converts this into a `LinkedHashMap` with `lines` as the key and the value is an `ArrayList` with `LinkedHashMaps`, which have `value`and `example` and so on.

Is there a way to read this json as an Object with a field `list` that is a List/Array containing objects which would fit (in this case, a simple object with `String value` as a field)?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this. This solution is based around `Gson` instead of `ObjectMapper`.
Basically Gson manages to convert arrays into the fields as I wanted it to happen here, instead of generating a lot of `LinkedHashMaps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Jackson in a straight-forward way.
For this you need to model the JSON structure by some Java classes.

First, you need a class for modeling the whole JSON content
(let us call it `Root`) with a `list` property.

```
public class Root {

    private List<Item> list;

    // public getter and setter (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Next, you need a class for modeling the list items
(let us call it `Item`) with a `value` property.

```
public class Item {

    private String value;

    // public getter and setter (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Then you are able to read JSON content into a  Java `Root` object by using
one of `ObjectMapper`'s [`readValue(..., Class<T>)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Class)) methods.
For example reading from a `File`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = objectMapper.readValue(new File("example.json"), Root.class);
```